# Changed EXIF dates and file attributes are not recognized on Android

Tags: images, exif

I had several jpeg images stored on a MicroSDXC card that had incorrect dates, year 2000, which were taken in 2010.

I inserted this SD card into slot and used [EXIFtool](https://exiftool.org/) to correct dates, which were correct afterwards - date information was stored in `DateTime`, `DateTimeOriginal`, `DateTimeDigitized`. I also changed `File created`, `File modified` date from the EXIF tag by using [BulkFileChanger](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html), so it shows the correct year in file system.

I used [TeraCopy](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy) to copy modified files onto SD card and used `Transfer: Data, Timestamps, Attributes, Streams` + Transfer options were set to "`Verify files after transfer`".

[image: IrfanView EXIF Info]
[image: TeraCopy Options tab]

I inserted this SD card back into Samsung Android phone and opened Google Photos app, the photos were still being showed wrongly at the end of timeline, in the year 2000. I cleaned cache of the app (Google photos and Gallery Go) and it didn't help.

I also saw that images on which I changed EXIF dates had prefix in their file names, something like `~~adt00000416~~DSC03040.JPG`, and are stored in `storage/01D0-A640/DCIM/folder/~~adt00000416~~DSC03040.JPG`.

I moved those files again from Windows to SD card but with TeraCopy `Streams` and `Attributes` disabled, but it didn't solve the issue on Android. File dates were showing correctly on the SD card (checked via irfanview exif info and file explorer) though and incorrect dates are nowhere to be seen.

[image]

Is it possible somehow Android has cached metadata of those files and perhaps even stores them hidden somewhere (hence that extra prefix in filename), and refuses to show metadata of newly modified files?

Comment: If everything shows the correct and updated dates and Android doesn't, then this is an Android issue and thus off-topic.

Comment: I wonder if Android is showing photo order based on file modification date and not the EXIF data?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I am not sure, the files that I transferred onto SD card didn't had any wrong dates anywhere. But android apps most likely sort by one of those 3 EXIF date tags in Google Photos and Gallery Go.

Comment: This seems to be an Android issue as [implied here](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/882182-app-sort-photos-exif-date.html): “Digital cameras add EXIF data to a photo, including date/time taken (from the camera), exposure and other details. However, most apps sort photos by their file date, NOT the EXIF date. This is the date when the file was copied to its current folder, which could be days or years later, very unlikely to be the true date when the photo was taken.”

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I had set File attributes (file date) from EXIF tag by using BulkFileChanger. The file attributes in Windows File explorer on SD card are exactly as corrected Date Taken in EXIF tag. I said in my OP post that there aren't wrong dates seen anywhere in the files that are located on the SD card.

Comment: @Rudolph Then this question definitely should be migrated top the Android specific SE site for further debugging since this is a truly oddball case. While others have voted to migrate it to the Android SE site, you can accelerate the process by flagging a moderator and asking them to migrate it.

Comment: gallery stores date in its own database, maybe it doesn't recognize the modified files. clear app data and check again

Comment: @alecxs already did.. I uninstalled app completely and installed again too (both GG and GP). But it started generating again thumbnails and timeline that was going back to year 2000... even though there are no files on that SD card that have year 2000 anywhere (I sorted them on windows file explorer and voidtools everything, and oldest ones were in 2008..

Comment: get the file name of any 2000 file. check `stat` from adb shell

Comment: can you check *'adb shell stat /storage/01D0-A640/DCIM/folder/~~adt00000416~~DSC03040.JPG'* from [usb-debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) please?